# Effect of holding a publicly traded royalty trust in a traditional IRA?

Tags: united-states, ira, investment-trusts

Does anyone know what the effect of holding a publicly traded trust like Mesabi Trust (MSB) in a traditional IRA account? This is what I've found so far on the Mesabi website:

> For income tax reporting purposes, each holder of units in the Trust
>   is considered to be a grantor or substitute grantor as well as a
>   beneficiary of the Trust, which means that Mesabi Trust is a
>   pass-through entity similar to a partnership. As such, in lieu of the
>   Trust paying income taxes, the unit holders report their pro rata
>   share of the various items of Trust income and deductions on their
>   income tax returns. This reporting is required whether or not the
>   earnings of the Trust are distributed to the unit holders. Trust
>   distributions should not be included in income tax returns as
>   "dividend income" and are not eligible for the dividends received
>   deduction for corporations or for the lower marginal tax rates
>   available for certain qualified dividends paid to individuals.
>
> You should have received or will receive shortly the 2018 calendar
>   year Forms 1099-INT and 1099-MISC which will report your share of
>   interest and gross royalty income.